# Extreme Switch QinQ

Tags: networking, switch

Trying to configure QinQ solution between two extreme switches facing an issue:

**| Error: 8: Port cannot belong to VLAN and a VMAN at the same time.|**

This port is not configured in any VLAN or VMAN as Untagged

This issue a get only in one of Switches.

The only difference between SW are the Image version running. But im not sure if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Documentation:

> You can configure both vMAN and VLAN simultaneously on the same physical port, but you must first change the vMAN Ethernet type to 0x8100

I think you should use command `configure vman ethertype 0x8100` before configuring ports for vMAN.

Comment: Adding a link to the docs you are quoting would be good.